# Convert all get parameters in one

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have .htaccess file with the code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) ?p=$1  [L]
```

but I want it to convert not only URI string to a get parameter p but also all other get parameters to p, in other words:
**domain.com/somewhere/somepage.html?foo=2**  ----> 
**domain.com/?p=urlencoded(somewhere/somepage.html?foo=2)**
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code in .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^p= [NC]
RewriteRule . /?p=%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Since `NE` flag is not provided here so mod_rewrite engine will encode your original URI before internally redirecting.